# AWS Neptune Create Index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

Can someone show a sample Gremlin query on create an index on a Neptune vertices?
I can't find some clear example on the AWS Neptune guide.

I know Neptune does implicit indexing, is there anyway I can re-enforce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Neptune indexes everything you add to a graph automatically, three different ways. There is an optional fourth index you can enable for some special edge cases. There is no, nor is there any need for, an index creation API. There really is nothing else that needs to be enforced. Currently, in terms of schema-like enforcement, all IDs have to be unique but no other constraints are applied. Neptune does support the addition of an Elastic Search / Open Search external index, and can manage that as well if needed, for lookups better suited to a Lucene engine.